# How to avoid scaling Pygame window when "make UI larger" is used in Windows?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Windows 10 option that makes user interface items slightly larger as usual (125%).

It looks like applications can decide whether to use this scaling or not.

My Pygame program seems to take this scaling into account. How can I make it ignore this so that a 100x100 Pygame screen is really 100x100 pixels on my display (not 125x125)?

Answer (score 9):

Found an answer from https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105750/pygame-fullsreen-display-issue:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```