# Why can't I find the close button on my pygame window?

Tags: python, windows

I am using the pygame module on pycharm. Each time I run any program, the pygame window opened cannot be minimised or closed from the window. I have to stop the program from running or use the taskbar instead. It is starting to get annoying. Is there anyway to fix this?

This is the code I use to launch a program (if it's of any use)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))
pygame.display.set_caption('Test Window')


run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

This is the resultant image when I run the program.
[image] That's the full screen. I did not crop anything out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running at 1920x1080, but PyGame somehow seems to think that's not the case, since the window that opens is much larger than 800x800.

From the screenshot, we can tell you're running on Windows. You may have some scaling accessibility settings enabled in the Windows, and Pygame uses that to scale up its full window as well.

Either compensate for the scaling if that's the case (by creating a smaller window, or computing what size it should be), or don't use the setting during development.

Have a look at:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
```

That may just resolve your issue, or you may need to look at passing some specific parameters to it to get the behaviour you want.

Edit:

After searching StackOverflow for that suggestion itself, it appears your question is really a duplicate of this: [How to avoid scaling Pygame window when "make UI larger" is used in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44334594/how-to-avoid-scaling-pygame-window-when-make-ui-larger-is-used-in-windows) but I decided to leave my answer up, because I feel you asked the question very clearly, and that's helpful.

Comment: To add do this, the default toolbar height is 40px, in the screenshot it's 60px, and the window is 1200px wide, so it's likely that scaling is set to 150%, likely due to a physically small screen such as an ultrabook.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance. It fixed my issues. I was not aware that my question was a duplicate; when constructing my question, the page you linked did not show up. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to make it such that I don't have to use that code? I mean, is there a way to fix the scaling issue in general?

Comment: Not really, it's not an issue or bug per se, it's a feature. Design your application to look good at an average resolution, and people can use scaling if it ends up being too small on their high DPI screens. However, if your applications requires pixel-perfect control (a pixel in your game/app is 1:1 with a real pixel) then you'll need to use this on Windows, and will need to check other OSes for potential similar issues.